# How to change authentication type on Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

We're building a simple script using the Tweepy Python library. We need to get some simple information on all of the accounts following our Twitter account.

Using the cursor Tweepy's built in this is quite easy, but we very rapidly hit the 15 request limit for the window. I've read that per-App (as opposed to per-user) authentication allows for 300 requests per minute, but I can't find anything in the Tweepy API that supports this.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `tweepy.AppAuthHandler` in the same way that you're using `OauthHandler`.

```
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(token, secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

For some reason, this isn't documented, but you can take a look at the code yourself on [GitHub](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/e2ba5b15024c375b2f2540c65a2ffd04a5f08121/tweepy/auth.py#L160).

It also depends what kinds of requests you're making. There are no resources with a 15 request user limit that have a 300 request app limit. You can consult [this chart](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) to determine the limits for user and app auth for each endpoint. In any case, using them in conjunction will at least double your requests.

Comment: Cracking thanks. No idea why this isn't documented :-/

Also yeah I've no idea where we got the 300 from, all the docs I've read have 30 so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not what information of your followers you are after exactly, but it might be part of the request [`followers/list`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list). If so, you can set the field `count` to `200` which is the maximum value, while the default is only `20`. That will save you some requests.

Comment: We'd done this already! But yeah that's good advice thanks ^_^